# Help with verb tense and modality differences among 'Whenever he'd knock, he was greeted' variations

Tags: modal-verbs, past-simple, modality

> 1. Whenever **he'd knock** on people's doors, requesting them to let him spend the night at their place, **he'd be greeted** with unfriendly faces.
> 2. Whenever **he'd knock** on people's doors, requesting them to let him spend the night at their place, **he was greeted** with unfriendly faces.
> 3. Whenever **he knocked** on people's doors, requesting them to let him spend the night at their place, **he'd be greeted** with unfriendly faces.
> 4. Whenever **he knocked** on people's doors, requesting them to let him spend the night at their place, **he was greeted** with unfriendly faces.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do all of them mean the same?

Comment: *Was be greeted* is an impossible and meaningless construction; you want simply *was greeted*. Otherwise, the sentences have the same meaning: there's no difference between the modal past and the simple past in this particular, because the *would*s all bear the same habitual or repetitive sense which is expressed by *whenever*.

Comment: Sorry for the errors, and thanks for pointing it out.
I tend to type fast, and that tends to lead to my making a lot of errors. 

So, it doesn't matter whether i use Would or Was in similar sentences as the ones i used earlier?

Comment: Exactly. In this context they have the same sense: on all occasions when this happened, that happened.

Comment: @StoneyB: I must say I don't particularly *like* the modal ***Whenever he'd knock...*** To me it always smacks of "overprecision" by non-native speakers, but I have started to get the impression from my years on ELU that AmE speakers have greater "linguistic competence inequality" (same as they have greater *income* inequality), and that there are therefore relatively more "over-competent" speakers who still cling to a form that's become very unusual in modern BrE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I feel the same way; but I don't think this is an overcompetent hangover from older use. I think it's rather part of a growing cisatlantic tendency to substitute *would VERB* for past-form *VERBed* in all sorts of conditionals, as if the past form expressed a hypothetical, even when the past form is merely a past; and it's strengthened in situations like this where habitual *would VERB* is employed in the matrix clause. It's really under-competent in traditional terms; but it's so common now it's merely adequately competent.

Comment: **We hated each other so much that whenever she'd call me, i'd drop her call.**

**We hated each other so much that whenever she called me, i'd drop her call.**

**We hated each other so much that whenever she called me, i dropped her call.** 

Which one would you use prefer to use?

Comment: @lekon: Per my previous comment, I *definitely* wouldn't include the first modal. I've no special preference re the second one, but most likely I'd say *...I **used to** hang up* (in BrE the line itself can "drop" accidentally, cutting off a call, but we don't intentionally drop calls).

Comment: Would you say the first sentence is grammatically incorrect? Or either of the three sentences grammatically incorrect?

Comment: lmao. What is "people's doors"........I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 0):

I think (2) and (3) are awkward at best and possibly incorrect, because the sentence jumps from conditional to simple mood. Also (2) has possibly a typo ("was be greeted" instead of "was greeted" ) making that phrase incorrect. The contraction "he'd" stands for 'he would' in this context, so (1) and (2) are speaking conditionally at the start, i.e. the action (knocking on doors) leads to the consequence (unfriendly faces) without implying that 'he' actually performed the action. so the next phrase needs to match. It might be prefaced with 'He was afraid that... "

(4) means that 'he' has actually performed the action, and every time this led to the consequence. This could be prefaced with 'He remembered that.." 
Also (4) has the same mistake ("was be")

Comment: I disagree -- I think those *would*s express habitual/repetitive modality rather than hypothetical modality.

Comment: In the sentences i used, i meant to convey something that had actually happened.
So, should still use woulds, or should i use simple past instead?

Comment: Using "would" or simple past doesn't change things. "Whenever" is the key for it being habitual, replacing with "if" would make it hypothetical.